# pkill not killing processes past immediate descendants of a given process

Tags: linux, bash, kill

I want to kill a chain of process e.g.

```
PID  PPID
100  XXX
101  100
102  101
```

When I use `pkill -P 100` PID 100 and 101 die as expected, but 102 is given init as it's PPID.

How can I force pkill to keep killing chained processes past a process's immediate descendants?

Comment: No you can't coerce `pkill` to do what you want. Each process has signal handling procedure. Some programs are designed to propagate the signal received to their children process, while others are meant to filter the signals. A web service is an example where supervisor daemon spawns child processes. It is not a good idea for supervisor daemon to propagate the signal down to children because if supervisor daemon dies, then web services go down with it. A database is an example where propagation of the signal is desirable by letting client processes die when log writer dies.

Answer (score 0):

try the following command:

> kill -9 100

You may find more information and options on kill documentation page:

> man kill